# How can I create a SQL varbinary of size greater than 8000 bytes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, varbinary, varbinarymax

I want to create a varbinary(16384) but cant because the size must be a max of 8000 or MAX.
I don't want to use MAX because I want an error thrown if the field size inserted is greater than 16384.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Can you use a check constraint on size > 16384?

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot now; you should add it as solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MAX.   Constrain the field and handle the error in the data layer / application.

It sounds like you are trying to push data to a table, and are depending upon the SQL Server to throw back an error.    IMO, this is too far 'down stream' to handle this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx the maximum size of varbinary is actually 2^31 - 1 for both 32-bit and 64-bit sql server